# Nuget seems to not work in Visual Studio 2017 (.net Core only)

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have the latest version of .NET Core installed as well as the latest version of visual studio 2017 and the latest version of NuGet. When I create a brand new ASP.NET Core Web Application (MVC) the project doesn't seem to create a working project. The Dependencies item has a warning label, when I click it I see NuGet with a warning label, and then under that is Microsfot.AspNetCore.All with a warning symbol.

[image]

When I attempt to do a NuGet restore it tells me that the "Operation failed as details for project WebApplicaction4 could not be loaded."  If I click the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All entry in the solution explorer my VS 2017 crashes.

I don't have this problem when I'm running .NET Framework, only Core.

EDIT:

-I'm running .NET Core 2.1.2

-When I run `dotnet new mvc --name WebApplication6` and then run `nuget restore` everything runs correctly, but when I open the app up in VS I get the same error display as in the image below

Here's the command line error message for an app created through visual studio's GUI:

```
C:\Users\Alan O'Kelly\source\repos\WebApplication4\WebApplication5>nuget restore
```

`WARNING: Could not load file or assembly 'HolographicExtensions.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
WARNING: Could not load file or assembly 'PerceptionSimulationExtensions.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
WARNING: Could not load file or assembly 'Windows.Devices.Printers.Extensions.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.5.180.51428' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
C:\Users\Alan O'Kelly\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\luqctw30.ycr.nugetrestore.targets(241,5): error MSB4062: The "NuGet.Build.Tasks.WarnForInvalidProjectsTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\WINDOWS\system32\nuget.exe. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\WINDOWS\system32\nuget.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\Users\Alan O'Kelly\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\dh1tmbpr.th1.nugetinputs.targets]`

Comment: Does restoring from the command line work?

Comment: What is the version of .net core installed? (cmd: dotnet --version)

Comment: If you recreate the project from the command line (by running the following command in a different directory: `dotnet new mvc --name WebApplication4`) what happens?

Comment: Is it only ASP NET Core MVC applications which cause this issue? What happens if you create a new console application (`dotnet new console`) and add a reference to the AspNetCore meta package (`dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetcore.All --version 2.0.3`) and open the project with Visual Studio?

Comment: When I run "nuget restore"  from the command line I get the following error: The "NuGet.Build.Tasks.WarnForInvalidProjectsTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\WINDOWS\system32\nuget.exe. (plus some more info)

Comment: which nuget.exe version are you using? it should be 4.5.0. also make sure your VS version is 15.5.*. Could you try moving the project to a folder without the `'` apostrophe in the path?

Comment: Also note that the screen shots show different applications - webapplication4 vs webapplication5

Comment: @MartinUllrich Changing the path to one that didn't include an apostrophe is the answer. It immediatly worked after that. Thank you! If you put that down as answer to the question I'll give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSbuild and NuGet can have issues with certain characters in the project's path.

Move the project out of the directory hierarchy containing the single quote `'` character.